# How to play audio as a stream in Ruby

Tags: ruby, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I'm trying to figure out a good way to play a WAV file as a stream using Ruby. I found this [CoreAudio](https://github.com/nagachika/ruby-coreaudio) gem but can't seem to get audio to play properly. When I run this code it just makes a very choppy, stuttery sound.

```
require 'coreaudio'
require 'thread'

BUFF_SIZE = 1024

Thread.abort_on_exception = true

song = CoreAudio::AudioFile.new("bleh.wav", :read)
outbuf = CoreAudio.default_output_device.output_buffer(BUFF_SIZE)

queue = Queue.new

read_song = Thread.start do
   loop do
     segment = song.read(BUFF_SIZE)
     queue.push(segment)
    end
end

play_song = Thread.start do
    while segment = queue.pop do
       outbuf << segment
    end
end

outbuf.start

sleep 10

read_song.kill.join
play_song.kill.join
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: take a look at this toturial http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails--net-18437 its really how on streaming music

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was with using two separate threads for input and output. I was able to get it working with a single thread:

```
play_song = Thread.start do
  while segment = song.read(BUFF_SIZE)
    outbuf << segment
  end
end
```

I'm guessing that using a shared queue between two threads was just too slow to play the audio back in real time.